# How to evaluate $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{10}{(z^2+1)^5}~dz$ using Cauchy's integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I evaluate $$\int_\Gamma \frac{10}{(z^2+1)^5}~dz$$ using Cauchy's integral formula, where $\Gamma$ is the positively orientated unit circle?

Now we have $$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^n}~dz=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(w)$$
So in our case would it just be that $$\int_\Gamma \frac{10}{(z^2+1)^5}~dz = \frac{2\pi i}{4!}f^{(4)}(-1)=0$$ but this would just be $0$ since the $4$th derivative is $0$?

Comment: That formula isn't appliable in your case in that form: observe that $\;z^2+1\;$ vanishes at $\;\pm i\;$ , not at $\;-1\;$ ., so your line of integration contains two singularities.

Comment: You can't use Cauchy's formula. Your singularity is at $z = \pm i$ which is on the circle.

Comment: I thought it was only $f(z)=10$ that has to be holomorphic on some simply connected set? Why do we care that the bottom bit vanishes on the the circle surely it is okay?

Comment: @David No, it's not. Read carefully CIF conditions. You will perhaps have to construct little circles around those singluraties. It looks messy.

Comment: It's not okay.  The integrand has rather nasty singularities on the circle, so the integral doesn't exist (except possibly in a Cauchy principal value sense).

Comment: Using your formula, the point $w$ needs to be in the interior of $\Gamma$. A point on $\Gamma$ is not in the interior of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Okay I see what is wrong with what I said. So if I took a point on the interior of $\Gamma$, $0$ say and replaced $z^2+1$ with just $z^2$ would the resulting integral be $0$ by the same logic as before with the new point?

Comment: If you have poles in the interior of $\Gamma$, you can use the residue formula.

Comment: I haven't covered those yet. Could you make a comment regarding my last post?